# How to make a smooth GoogleMap camera animation?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make a smooth camera animation when we update the GoogleMap camera position. [This is how its working right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp66X.jpg). Currently I am doing this on every location update I am recieving. But it is not smooth as seen in the gif. I have also tried passing the duration in milliseconds in the animateCamera() method, but it only changes the duration of the animation. How can I achieve a smooth camera animation?

```
val latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
val cameraPosition =
    CameraPosition.Builder()
                .bearing(bearing)
                .target(latLng)
                .zoom(authStore.mapZoomLevel)
                .build()
            val cameraUpdateFactory =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)
            mMap?.animateCamera(cameraUpdateFactory, cancelableCallback)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with smooth? If you prefer a kind of continuous movement you may give the animation more time, such that it just ends before the next update appears. But from your question it looks like you tried something like that already.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, still it was not continuous. I have also tried valueAnimator, and called the gMap.moveCamera() for every new LatLng I was getting from the valueAnimator , but it was causing more problems like I cant zoom in/out and pan when the camera was updating continuously.

Comment: I am setting the duration in the animateCamera call to 950 (msecs), while expecting a location update every second. This works fine for me.